# Creating a list of objects containing std::atomic

Tags: c++, list, c++14, atomic

I have a list of objects stored in a list that represent chunks of read-only memory for threads to use.  each chunk object has an atomic that acts as a reference count, pretty simple.

I have a problem though, `std::list<Type>` apparently needs a copy constructor for `Type`?, and having an `std::atomic` as a member of `Type` deletes the default copy constructor of the chunk object's class.  I'm pretty sure a list isn't allowed to copy or move it's elements around whatsoever in memory, so why would it require that constructor?

Anywho, **the question**, how might I have a list of objects containing `std::atomic`?  The atomic cannot change address, I have no interest in copying or moving it, so it seems I need to use something other than `std::list`?

Comment: The requirements of `T` for `std::list<T>` depends on the version of c++ you are asking about. For c++11 and later, non-copyable types are fine in `std::list` provided you don't try any operation that would need to copy an element.

Comment: Why `std::list` and not `std::vector`? A vector almost always out-performs a list. In fact, a list is just about the *worst* data structure you can ask a modern CPU to work with.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - The list elements are just big hunks of memory, a few kilobytes.  They have to remain at the same address though, if they move around the worker threads will lose track of them

Comment: Can you provide example code that produces the error?

Comment: Anne, why not just do `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Type>>`?.  Or `even std::vector<Type*>` and manage the deletion of each item when you are done with the collection.

Comment: Vector of pointers, or vector of unique_ptr, or vector of shared_ptr?

Comment: The hate for `std::list` is real. It's not a great container, but if you want to preserve iterators, references and pointers it does the job.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I see, the only list methods I'm using is `push_back()` and `front()` and `erase()`, maybe one of those requires copying?

Comment: @AnneQuinn Try `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` as it constructs the element in-place. Provide it with `Type`'s constructor arguments.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - `emplace_back` was just what the doctor ordered, thank you!!

Comment: @selbie what a terrible suggestion to manage pointers manually!

Comment: @AnneQuinn don't listen to `std::list` haters. If you want a container which allows insertion in the middle and preserve iterators, list is the one and only container which does the job.  On the other hand, if you are only interested in references (i.e. as long as objects physically do not move, invalidating iterators is ok) and only push in the back, `std::deque` would be a better choice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Your last comment is an answer.