# How to write a const iterator idiomatically?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a linked list implementation, but I've gotten stuck on how to implement a const iterator accessed through `cbegin()` alongside the normal iterator. Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ListNode {
public:
    ListNode<T>* next_;
    ListNode<T>* prev_;
    T data_;

    ListNode():
        next_(nullptr),
        prev_(nullptr)
    {}
};

template <typename T>
class ListIterator
{
    typedef ListNode<T> node;
    typedef ListNode<T>* pointer;
    pointer p_;

public:
    ListIterator(pointer p) : p_(p) {}
    T& operator*() { return p_->data_; }
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    typedef ListNode<T> node;
    typedef ListNode<T>* pointer;
    typedef ListIterator<T> iterator;
    typedef ListIterator<const T> constIterator;

    List() :
        head_(nullptr),
        tail_(nullptr),
        size_(0)
    {}

    void pushBack(pointer p) {
        p->next_ = nullptr;
        p->prev_ = nullptr;

        if (size_ == 0) {
            head_ = p;
        } else {
            tail_->next_ = p;
            p->prev_ = tail_;
        }

        tail_ = p;
        ++size_;
    }

    iterator begin() { return head_; }
    iterator end() { return nullptr; }
    constIterator cbegin() { return head_; }
    constIterator cend() { return nullptr; }

private:
    pointer head_;
    pointer tail_;
    unsigned int size_;
};

class Dog {
public:
    int age;
};

int main() {
    auto list = List<Dog>();
    auto dogNode = ListNode<Dog>();
    list.pushBack(&dogNode);
    auto b = list.cbegin();
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the error
`error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'List<Dog>::pointer' (aka 'ListNode<Dog> *') to function return type
      'List<Dog>::constIterator' (aka 'ListIterator<const Dog>')`

This error makes sense to me, but I can't figure out a good workaround that doesn't involve writing a separate `ConstListIterator` class (this works, but it feels wrong to copy-pasta all the operator overloading code from `ListIterator`--most of it omitted from this sample).

In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55834/linked-list-with-iterators), the author uses the approach of parametrizing `ListIterator` with `TNode`, which in this context would be `ListNode<Dog>` rather than `Dog`. The problem with this approach is that then the `operator*` can't return an actual `Dog`, because the `ListIterator` class doesn't know about the typename `Dog`. So that solution just hardcodes in the type of `data_`, so you lose all the benefits of the metaprogramming.

Is there a trick to make this work nicely, or should I just have a separate `ConstListIterator` class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the node type be a template argument for the iterator is reasonable and allows

```
using constIterator=ListIterator<const ListNode<T>>;
```

which conveniently precludes structural modifications as well as content modifications.  It allows `cbegin` to work as written (implicitly adding `const` to `head_`’s type).  It also allows `T` to be `const` itself (which works for a linked list: it [never needs to relocate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53963721/8586227)).

To define `operator*`, you can just use `auto`:

```
auto& operator*() const {return p_->data_;}
```

The constness of `*p_` carries over to `data_` and thence to the return type.

## Before C++14

In C++11, you can equip `ListNode` with

```
using value_type=T;
```

and use type traits like `is_const` and `conditional` to derive `const T` from `const ListNode<T>`.

In C++03, you can directly write a SFINAE-based trait for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that you are trying to return `head`, which is of type `ListNode<T>*` from a function with the return type `constIterator` AKA `ListIterator<const T>`.

To answer your question, the only difference between an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` is that a `const_iterator` returns a const reference to the `value_type` of the container instead of just a reference. Therefore, passing `const T` as the template argument should result in the desired functionality. Since `operator*` returns `T&`, if `T` is instead `const T`, then it returns `const T&`, which is correct. It seems that the issue you were having was because you were returning the wrong types from your `iterator` functions, as noted above.

Your iterator functions should instead look like this:

```
iterator begin() { return iterator{head_}; }
iterator end() { return iterator{nullptr}; }
constIterator cbegin() { return constIterator{head_}; }
constIterator cend() { return constIterator{nullptr}; }
```

This returns `iterator` and `constIterator` objects that are constructed using the pointers `head_` and `nullptr`, which is what you want.

The template parameter you used for the iterators, the `value_type` of the list, is correct.

Comment: Edited to reflect that fact.

Comment: Edited again. Thanks.